# Filtering start time of one row and end time of another row using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataset with repeated activities. I need to filter those in such a way that I have start date of the first occurence and end date of last occurence along with the single activity.

Dataframe:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC0SP.png]

Kindly refer the link provided.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC0SP.png. Kindly refer this link

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , its completely dummy data

Answer (score 0):

First convert columns to datetimes if necessary:

```
df[['Start','End']] = df[['Start','End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

And then aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) or 
[`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) or `min` and `max` per groups:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Activity', as_index=False).agg({'Start':'first', 'End':'last'})
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('Activity', as_index=False).agg({'Start':'min', 'End':'max'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying is to club the occurence of 'activities' with respect to there start and end time.
For example if you're trying club 'a', then start time of first 'a' and end time of last 'a' is what you're trying to get.